# Execute a command with JSON string in python

Tags: python

How do we execute a shell command with a JSON string in python?

The command is like:

```
tool --options '{"oldTool" : "yes"}'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use argparse to capture command line arguments

Comment: Is `tool` the python script you are writing or some command line program your python script must invoke?

Comment: I don't know why you're accepting a JSON string, but I HOPE you aren't accepting an arbitrary 3rd party string to execute on the command line as your webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

I would import call from subprocess (`from subprocess import call`) and then use the call command: `call("tool", "--options '{\"oldTool\" : \"yes\"}')` (Backslashes can be replaced with whatever the python escape character is). Although, your question is rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.check_output()`. This will allow you to execute the script and capture its output:

```
import json
import subprocess

data = {'oldTool' : 'yes'}
output = subprocess.check_output(['tool', '--options', json.dumps(data)])
```